# When is computed property going to be triggered, VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I've got a form with an `<input>` and '' in it. I would like to implement `computed property` which would monitor `<input>` and every time user deletes everything from this `<input>`, `computed property` should return `<select>` to it's default state.

Here is the code:

```
<input class="form-control"/>
<select v-model="selectModel">
   <option>Please select</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
   <option>No</option>
</select>



<script>
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
       return {
          selectModel: '';
       }
    },
    computed: {
       input_empty: function() {
            var inp = getElementByClass('form-control');
            if (inp == '') {
                selectModel = "Please select";
            }
       }
    }
 })
 </script>
```

When this `computed property` is going to be triggered? I was thinking that it's going to be triggered every time I type something into input field, or when I delete everything from it, so I have put a breakpoint onto first line in computed function, but it never gets triggered.

Comment: Don't use a computed for that. `computed` as the name says is something that can be computed from values of your viewmodel.

Comment: @connexo you are right actually, I am pretty new at this and now I see that I should use `watch` instead of `computed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch input's value and whenever it's an empty string, you would also reset your `selectModel`: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/395052/

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <input class="form-control" v-model="textInput" />
  <select v-model="selectModel">
     <option value="" disabled>Please select</option>
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        selectModel: '',
      textInput: 'input'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    textInput: function () {
      if(this.textInput.trim() === '') {
        this.selectModel = ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a methods do what you need and wrap your input with `@change`, so you can call a method with your code

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <input class="form-control" v-model="myinput" @change="checkInput">
<select v-model="selectModel">
   <option value="Please select" seleceted>Please select</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

  </div>
</div>
```

**vue code**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () =>  ({
    selectModel: '',
    myinput: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    checkInput() {
      if (this.myinput === '') {
        console.log('here')
        this.selectModel = 'Please select'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the `watch` is more suitable for me at this moment